# Installing matplotlib on Ubuntu: ImportError

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror

My platform:

Ubuntu 13.04, Python 2.7.4.

Installing matplotlib failed, ImportError: No module named pyplot.

I have tried many ways such as

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

and easy install, install from source..., I'm folllowing http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html

But none of them works, This ImportError always happen, Anyone can help?

**EDIT** The trace back:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-82be63b7783c> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib

/home/wuhuijia/matplotlib.py in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import scipy.optimize as so
      4 
      5 def find_confidence_interval(x, pdf, confidence_level):

ImportError: No module named pyplot
```

Comment: Can you show us the trace back of the import error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your script is named `matplotlib.py`. Python will first look locally when importing modules, that is, on the directory itself. Thus, Python imports *your script* (and not the installed matplotlib) when you execute `import matplotlib.pyplot`, and since your script has no submodule `pyplot`, it fails.

Rename your script to something else (e.g., `testmpl.py`) and you should be fine.

Comment: I didn't get this... and I have the same problem.. can you detail it more?

Comment: Why renaming the script would solve the problem? it is not clear to me